# Проблема передачи аргументов из D программы в C библиотеку. Или тупо незнание строк :/

Tags: dll, d

D код

```
void function (const char *)_MY_DL_Initialize;

void myDProga_DL_Initialize(string dl_name)
{
    ... загрузка длл и получение адресов здесь
    writeln("IN D: ", dl_name );
    _MY_DL_Initialize( dl_name.ptr );
}
```

далее C библиотека

```
D_API int D_CDECL MY_DL_Initialize(const char * name )
{
    printf("IN C++: %s\n", name);
    ... всё, name is null
}
```

Вывод

```
IN D: MYDLL.dll
IN C++: (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

-_-

Нужно было использовать `extern(C)` в месте где создаются указатели на СИ функции.

```
extern(C)
{
    void function (const char *)_MY_DL_Initialize;
}
```